# How Can I "append" dictionaries into a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to tried to seperate each dictionary inside the list `names` to their own category depending on the first letter of the name. I'm pretty new to coding and I have tried a to use other functions like `update` but I have been unsuccessful in achieving the end result. I don't know how to append dictionaries inside a nested dictionary.

```
names = [{"name":"alpha"}, {"name":"apple"}, {"name":"bravo"}, {"name":"charlie"}, {"name":"chucky"}]

foo = {
    "a" : {},
    "b" : {},
    "c" : {}
}
```

End result should be:

```
foo = {
    "a" : {
        {"name":"alpha"},
        {"name":"apple"}
    },
    "b" : {
        {"name":"bravo"}
    },
    "c" : {
        {"name":"charlie"},
        {"name":"chucky"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code and current results or errors

Comment: Your "end result" does not make sense. You can't use dictionaries holding other dictionaries as a list. Just try to write `{{"name":"alpha"}, {"name":"apple"}}` and see what happens. What about using a list of dictionaries like the one you have in `names`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to **ask a specific question**. Note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; telling us that you are "new" or "don't know how" to do something is not useful. If you "tried to use" something, we can only possibly explain the problem if we actually see *how* you tried - please show that code, and explain *what* went wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are key,value pairs so your desired output isn't possible.

Also dictionary keys must be unique, so calling `update` on a dictionary using a key that already exists will simply overwrite the value.

It sounds like what you want is to have a list as the nested structure like this:

```
foo = {}
for item in names:
    char = item["name"][0]
    try:
        foo[char].append(item)
    except KeyError:
        foo[char] = [item]
print(foo)
```

output

```
foo = {
    "a" : [
        {"name":"alpha"},
        {"name":"apple"}
    ],
    "b" : [
        {"name":"bravo"}
    ],
    "c" : [
        {"name":"charlie"},
        {"name":"chucky"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #try this

    names = [{"name":"alpha"}, {"name":"apple"}, {"name":"bravo"}, 
    {"name":"charlie"}, {"name":"chucky"}]

    foo = {
    "a" : {},
    "b" : {},
    "c" : {}
    }

    for keys in foo.keys():
      lists=[]
      for name in names:
        for key,val in name.items():
            if val[0].lower()==keys.lower():
                lists.append(name)
      foo[keys]=lists
    print(foo)
```

**bro you doing some mistake here :

```
   "a" : {
        {"name":"alpha"},
        {"name":"apple"}
    }
```

-dict always accept key and value pair not only value because it's
happen,if in future you try to append dict without key so always use list
not dict**

```
    foo = {
           "a" : [
                  {"name":"alpha"},
                  {"name":"apple"}
                 ],
           "b" : [
                  {"name":"bravo"}
                 ],
           "c" : [
                  {"name":"charlie"},
                  {"name":"chucky"}
                 ]
          }
```

Answer (score -2):

The below dictionary is invalid as you cannot have dictionaries separated by commas as the sole contents of another dictionary. A dictionary is supposed to contain key, value pairs.

```
foo = {
    "a" : {
        {"name":"alpha"},
        {"name":"apple"}
    },
    "b" : {
        {"name":"bravo"}
    },
    "c" : {
        {"name":"charlie"},
        {"name":"chucky"}
    }
}
```

For example in the below key, value pair `a` is the key, it is fine till this part. The part `{{"name":"alpha"},{"name":"apple"}}` is the problem where you have dictionaries separated by commas within another dictionary, this will result in error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

```
"a" : {
        {"name":"alpha"},
        {"name":"apple"}
    },
```

However, you can have a list of dictionaries as the value of a key.

You can use the below method to create one.

```
import json

names = [{"name":"alpha"}, {"name":"apple"}, {"name":"bravo"}, {"name":"charlie"}, {"name":"chucky"}]

foo = {}

for item_dict in names:
    val = item_dict["name"]
    foo.setdefault(val[0], []).append(item_dict)

print(json.dumps(foo, indent=2))
```

This will output:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "name": "alpha"
    },
    {
      "name": "apple"
    }
  ],
  "b": [
    {
      "name": "bravo"
    }
  ],
  "c": [
    {
      "name": "charlie"
    },
    {
      "name": "chucky"
    }
  ]
}
```